# Numpy np.arange causes Kernel to die and restart

Tags: python, numpy, debugging

I am trying to create an x-axis with ticks at a frequency that I set so that all my figures look the same. I have an array of 534 datetime values called summertime and I am trying to make the x-axis between those datetime with a frequency of 10.

```
 ax1.xaxis.set_ticks( np.arange(summertime.min(), summertime.max(), 10))
```

The code ran for a couple days before crashing while I was changing variables and such. No errors come up, it just says it's running for a while then causes the kernel to crash. Also, it looks like it's using up most of the memory on my computer to run this. I watched it burn through 20gb while trying to run this.

Not exactly sure what's going on but would very much like some advice on how to fix this bug.

[Ran the code. Been waiting 2 min. Memory jumped from 54% to 92%. Whole computer slowing down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNw99.png)

[The aftermath. Took several minutes and all computer functions slowed down. It quit Microsoft Word and Chrome suddenly (without asking) then restarted Kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvJqZ.png)

Comment: What are the values of `summertime.min()` and `summertime.max()`?

Comment: summertime.min() = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 24, 0, 10, 40)   
summertime.max() = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 16, 0, 8, 32)    
max - min = datetime.timedelta(22, 86272)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when you call

```
np.arange(summertime.min(), summertime.max(), 10)
```

the units of that value `10` is the smallest unit of the `datetime` object, which is *microseconds*.  Given your starting and ending dates, that call to `arange` is attempting to create an array with length 198707200000.  That would require more than a terabyte of memory.

You said "I am trying to make the x-axis between those datetime with a frequency of 10", but you don't say what the units of that value of 10 are.  10 minutes?  Hours? Seconds?

Let's say it is 10 hours.  You can specify that increment as either the number of microseconds, or as a `datetime.timedelta` object.  For example,

```
In [43]: mn = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 24, 0, 10, 40) 

In [44]: mx = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 16, 0, 8, 32)

In [45]: np.arange(mn, mx, 10*3600*1000000)  # Increment is 10 hours, expressed in microseconds
Out[45]: 
array(['2015-07-24T00:10:40.000000', '2015-07-24T10:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-24T20:10:40.000000', '2015-07-25T06:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-25T16:10:40.000000', '2015-07-26T02:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-26T12:10:40.000000', '2015-07-26T22:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-27T08:10:40.000000', '2015-07-27T18:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-28T04:10:40.000000', '2015-07-28T14:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-29T00:10:40.000000', '2015-07-29T10:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-29T20:10:40.000000', '2015-07-30T06:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-30T16:10:40.000000', '2015-07-31T02:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-31T12:10:40.000000', '2015-07-31T22:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-01T08:10:40.000000', '2015-08-01T18:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-02T04:10:40.000000', '2015-08-02T14:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-03T00:10:40.000000', '2015-08-03T10:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-03T20:10:40.000000', '2015-08-04T06:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-04T16:10:40.000000', '2015-08-05T02:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-05T12:10:40.000000', '2015-08-05T22:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-06T08:10:40.000000', '2015-08-06T18:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-07T04:10:40.000000', '2015-08-07T14:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-08T00:10:40.000000', '2015-08-08T10:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-08T20:10:40.000000', '2015-08-09T06:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-09T16:10:40.000000', '2015-08-10T02:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-10T12:10:40.000000', '2015-08-10T22:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-11T08:10:40.000000', '2015-08-11T18:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-12T04:10:40.000000', '2015-08-12T14:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-13T00:10:40.000000', '2015-08-13T10:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-13T20:10:40.000000', '2015-08-14T06:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-14T16:10:40.000000', '2015-08-15T02:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-15T12:10:40.000000', '2015-08-15T22:10:40.000000'], dtype='datetime64[us]')

In [46]: np.arange(mn, mx, datetime.timedelta(hours=10))  # Increment is 10 hours, expressed using a datetime.timedelta
Out[46]: 
array(['2015-07-24T00:10:40.000000', '2015-07-24T10:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-24T20:10:40.000000', '2015-07-25T06:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-25T16:10:40.000000', '2015-07-26T02:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-26T12:10:40.000000', '2015-07-26T22:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-27T08:10:40.000000', '2015-07-27T18:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-28T04:10:40.000000', '2015-07-28T14:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-29T00:10:40.000000', '2015-07-29T10:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-29T20:10:40.000000', '2015-07-30T06:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-30T16:10:40.000000', '2015-07-31T02:10:40.000000',
       '2015-07-31T12:10:40.000000', '2015-07-31T22:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-01T08:10:40.000000', '2015-08-01T18:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-02T04:10:40.000000', '2015-08-02T14:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-03T00:10:40.000000', '2015-08-03T10:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-03T20:10:40.000000', '2015-08-04T06:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-04T16:10:40.000000', '2015-08-05T02:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-05T12:10:40.000000', '2015-08-05T22:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-06T08:10:40.000000', '2015-08-06T18:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-07T04:10:40.000000', '2015-08-07T14:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-08T00:10:40.000000', '2015-08-08T10:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-08T20:10:40.000000', '2015-08-09T06:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-09T16:10:40.000000', '2015-08-10T02:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-10T12:10:40.000000', '2015-08-10T22:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-11T08:10:40.000000', '2015-08-11T18:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-12T04:10:40.000000', '2015-08-12T14:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-13T00:10:40.000000', '2015-08-13T10:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-13T20:10:40.000000', '2015-08-14T06:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-14T16:10:40.000000', '2015-08-15T02:10:40.000000',
       '2015-08-15T12:10:40.000000', '2015-08-15T22:10:40.000000'], dtype='datetime64[us]')
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I'm an idiot. I was trying to get it to give me back every tenth data point. So it would give me 2015-7-30 10:00:00 then 2015-7-30 20:00:00, etc. instead of automatically setting the interval for me. I did your fix and it worked but it's now giving me tick labels that just say "2015" instead of the full datetime value( i.e. 2015-7-30 20:00:00. Do you have any idea how to make the labels the datetime value?

Comment: I know it is possible, but I don't recall the details.  That's a matplotlib question;  try searching the matplotlib tag for something like "tick labels dates".

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in syntax. Problem might be that range summertime.max() - summertime.min() is too much large.

I just executed

```
    ax4.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0.5,100,10))
```

on my computer and it runs fine. But if I execute

```
   ax4.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0.5,100000000,10))
```

it gives me memory error.

Could you please share the information about **summertime** data frame.

Comment: summertime is an object with values in an array that are in datetime so datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 1, 0, 36, 16) comes out as 2015-8-1 00:36:16 (August 1, 2015 at 12:36:16 am) on the x-axis. We have 534 points that are measured every 45 minutes. Data are from July 24 [datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 24, 0, 10, 40) ] to August 15 [ datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 16, 0, 8, 32) ].

Comment: As cleared by Warren Weckesser the array created by 
np.arange(summertime.min(), summertime.max(), 10) will require too much memory which will exceed the RAM.